# List xlsx sheetnames with R

Tags: r, xlsx

Is it possible to generate a list of sheetnames within an xlsx file? Or perhaps, can I check if a sheet name exists, and if not, proceed with some designated function?

Answer (score 18):

With **xlsx** library you can get the list of the sheets in an existing workbook with getSheets():

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(your_xlsx_file)
sheets <- names(getSheets(wb))
```

Comment: I think you want names(getSheets(wb))

Comment: I also propose to edit the second line to `names(getSheets(wb))`, as suggested by [Gerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372664/gerry).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I have done that with the [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xlsx) package which (just like the [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/package=XLConnect) package) uses a Java backend with the Apache POI code -- so it is cross-platform.

Comment: I glossed right over the getSheets function, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above solutions worked for a big xlsx of more than 300 sheets.

Only this worked in my case:

```
library(openxlsx)
sheetNames <- getSheetNames("filename.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with the RODBC package:

```
h <- odbcConnectExcel2007("file.xlsx")
sqlTables(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get excel or workbook file sheet names using R xlsx package, load your workbook or excel file, in my case e.g. name of excel file is "input_4_r.xlsx"

```
> wb<-loadWorkbook("input_4_r.xlsx")
```

See the list of files, here it shows 2 sheets in my example case
in my example, I have not named first sheet and kept the default
but 2nd sheet, I named as "name city" and hence the output below.

```
> getSheets(wb)
$Sheet1
[1] "Java-Object{Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml}"

$`name city`
[1] "Java-Object{Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml}"
```

You can see the names of sheetnames as below.

```
> names(getSheets(wb))
[1] "Sheet1"    "name city"
```

To get the name of specific index of sheet, e.g. passing [2] in my case for 2nd sheet.

```
> names(getSheets(wb))[2]
[1] "name city"
```

Assumption for above is xlsx package is installed and loaded in R

Answer (score 0):

A oneline solution using `openxlsx` would be

```
openxlsx::getSheetNames('your/file.xlsx')
```

Comment: You would have to install the package. `install.packages("openxlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

The following approach could also be considered with the RDOMClient R package :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/my_Excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File)
nb_Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()$Count()
sheets_Names <- character(nb_Sheets)

for(i in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  sheets_Names[i] <- xlWbk$Sheets(i)$Name()
}
```