# Excel sheet to Rmarkdown

Tags: python, r, excel, r-markdown

I have a excel workbook which have n number of worksheets in it. Each sheet contains different number of tables in it of different length. so, is there a way that I can convert them into Rmarkdown tables in just one go. The method I currently know is to copy and past the table on some converter and it converts but its static. Is there a way that in R or python  I just read the excel file and the tables of excel are converted into Rmarkdown tables. like I don't want to copy and paste each table to convert.

Comment: Can you include the code you currently use to deal with this issue? could you also provide an indication of what the excel tables look like, maybe extract them into the question as data.frames? All this is to make your question a [reprex]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider xlsx package and xlsx::read.xlsx. According to [Geza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946449/geza) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24412018/9959115) you should before take care of the workbooks sheets names. So :

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("path-to-your_xlsx/file.xlsx")
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
namesl <- names(sheets)
```

Then you can made a data.frame for each sheets, for e.g with read.xlsx or read.xlsx2, like in the following code :

```
> for(1 in 1:length(namesl)) {   assign(paste(namesl[i]), 
> # create an object in your env. with assign()
> 
> xlsx::read.xlsx("path-of-your-workbook.xlsx", # read a workbook-sheet
> sheetName = paste(namesl[i]), as.data.frame = T, header = T 
> # As you like for importing opts, need a check for correct importation.
>                                     )
>                             }
```

In order to create a data.frame by sheets in the workbook (each data.frame had the same name as a workbook sheet) and fill it with the content of the sheet.

Excellent day